# Calculate Coordinates on the Beeline between two Coordinates on a Spheroid/Ellipsoid (Earth)

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, projection-mathematics

I have two coordinates of locations on the earth and want to calculate points in between these two coordinates on the Beeline, for example the coordinate in the middle or at 10%.

I am able to do this on a plane.  However, I am not sure how to do this on a spheroid or ellipsoid. It doesn't need to be 100% accurate, but the planar version is definitely not good enough.

As asked by Ian Turton, I tried a planar formula, in Java this could look like this (taken from [jts](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/LineSegment.html#pointAlong-double-)):

```
  public Coordinate pointAlong(double segmentLengthFraction)
  {
    Coordinate coord = new Coordinate();
    coord.x = p0.x + segmentLengthFraction * (p1.x - p0.x);
    coord.y = p0.y + segmentLengthFraction * (p1.y - p0.y);
    return coord;
  }
```

I had a look at JTS as well, but I could only find a planar (`LineSegment#pointAlong`) version for this, not sure if they offer a different version?

Comment: what language are you using? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @IanTurton as mentioned in the question, I tried for example `LineSegment#pointAlong`, which uses a planar approach. I am using Java, but I am not necessarily looking for a language specific solution. I am looking for an algorithm or formula. That's why I didn't mention any language specifics and did not add any language specific tags. A solution in Java would be fine for me, but a general formula would be great as well.

Comment: I added a code example @IanTurton, but I am not sure if this improves the question, as this is obviously not the correct approach?

Comment: Robin have you tried geograpiclib, which has code for geodesics on an ellipsoid?https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/2009-03/geodesic.html

Comment: @HansErren this looks really promising, I will have a look thanks!

Comment: @HansErren thanks, the geodesic line fixed this indeed. Do you want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source library geograpiclib has code for geodesics on an ellipsoid in various programming languages
https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/2009-03/geodesic.html

Main page:
https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/

Resource page for

```
    * C. F. F. Karney, Transverse Mercator with an accuracy of a few nanometers, J. Geodesy 85(8), 475–485 (Aug. 2011); preprint arXiv:1002.1417; addenda.

    * C. F. F. Karney, Geodesics on an ellipsoid of revolution, arXiv:1102.1215 (Feb. 2011).

    * C. F. F. Karney, Algorithms for geodesics, J. Geodesy 87(1), 43–55 (Jan. 2013); DOI: 10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z; addenda.
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. An example for Java can be found here: 
https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/java/net/sf/geographiclib/GeodesicLine.html